# After adding subtitles the second audio track gone

Tags: ffmpeg, video, encoding, subtitles

I have a video with 2 audio tracks.

After using the following command line
the other audio track is gone

```
ffmpeg -i "movie.mkv" -i "subtitles.ass" -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy "movie with subtitles.mkv"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to add mapping: `ffmpeg -i "movie.mkv" -i "subtitles.ass" -map 0 -map 1 -c copy "movie with subtitles.mkv"`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the `-map` options, then by [ffmpeg Documentation](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/27779/18155) :

> ffmpeg will pick one stream, when available, from among all the inputs.

It means that it selects only one video stream, **only one audio stream**, and only one subtitle stream (by criteria listed in that doc).

So you have to use `-map` option:

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mkv -i subtitles.ass -map 0:v -c copy -map 0:a -c copy -map 1:s -c copy "movie with subtitles.mkv"
```

---

*The detailed explanation:*

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mkv -i subtitles.ass ...
```

**Input files** are introduced with `-i` options, and are enumerated from `0`, so

- `movie.mkv` has the number `0`,
- `subtitles.ass` has the number `1`.

This number is the first one in every `-map` option:

```
... -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 - map 0:a:1 -map 1:s ...
```

After the semicolon (`:`) may be the **stream specifier**, in your case:

- `v` for video stream
- `a` for audio stream
- `s` for subtitle stream

If there is *only one* video stream or *only one* audio stream or *only one* subtitle stream in a particular input file, there is nothing more to specify:

```
... -map 0:v ... -map 1:s ...
```

In your more complicated case with more audio streams, after another semicolon you may specify its `ordinal number`, enumerated again from `0`:

```
... -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 ...
```

or – in your case - you my simply omit ordinal number to select *all* audio streams:

```
... -map 0:a ...
```

---

*Note:*

The offered command may be further simplified.

To better understand stream specifiers (as e.g. `0:a:1`), see [my another answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/27779/18155) – at least the picture near the end of it.